# Co-authorship graph

Tags: literature-search

I am currently building a reading list targeted towards a certain list of 5-10 authors. They all work under the umbrella of wireless communications (separated by their own subfields), and I would like to efficiently go through their recent works. To facilitate the search, I would like to know their "affinity" towards each other via co-authorship links. I am hoping this might shed light into the development of their ideas.

My question is: is there a resource for finding (possibly indirect) connections between authors?

The best I could find is [DBLP](https://dblp.uni-trier.de) but this only gives the list of authors who are direct co-authors. Also, [this](https://proto-knowledge.blogspot.com/2015/02/tools-to-visualize-connections-between.html) link suggests Visual Explorer from Microsoft Academic, but it seems to be no longer available.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can have a look at [csauthors.net](https://www.csauthors.net/distance). It uses the DBLP database to find the co-authorship distance between two authors, and also provides the list of papers co-authored by any two authors forming a link.

As with any such resource (including DBLP), you need to be careful about spurious links created due to confusing between authors with the same name. Unfortunately, if this does happen there does not seem to be any way to easily find the true shortest path, however.

Screenshot for reference:
[image]

Example for list of papers co-authored:
[image]

<sub>Note: I am not affiliated to this website in any way.</sub>